# React js rendered value of state is one step behind

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to react js. I have created a project through the **create-react-app** which is actually an "online test application". I am facing a problem in one module which is of the test screen [which looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rKTKv.png). In my jsx code, I am rendering value of state variables like this.

```html
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Button, Radio, FormGroup } from 'react-bootstrap';
import Aux from '../../Auxilary/Auxilary';
import { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
 
import './TestScreen.css';

class TestScreen extends Component{
    
    state = {
        total_questions:60,
        current_question:1,
        time: 50,
        minutes: null,
        seconds: null
    };
    changeQuestion = () => {
        const question = this.state.current_question;
        this.setState({current_question: question+1});
    };
    componentDidMount(){
        const self = this;
        
        
       let timer = setInterval(function() {
            const newTime = self.state.time -1;
            const minute = Math.floor(self.state.time/60);
            const second = ("0" + self.state.time%60).slice(-2);
            self.setState({minutes: minute, seconds: second, time: newTime},() =>{
                console.log("Value of state Time: " + self.state.time);
            });
            
          
        }, 1000)
    }
   
    render(){
        
        return(
            <Aux>
                <div className="question-timer">
                    <div className="question-number">
                        <h3>Question {this.state.current_question}/{this.state.total_questions}</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div className="test-timer">
                        {this.state.time === 0 ?  <Redirect to='/' /> : console.log("Some Error Occured")}
                        <h3>{this.state.minutes}:{this.state.seconds}</h3>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="test-window">
                    <div className="test-question-statement">
                        <h2><label>Test Question Statement</label></h2>
                    </div>
                    <div className="question-options">
                    
                    <FormGroup>
                        <Radio name="radioGroup">
                            Option 1
                        </Radio>{' '}
                        <Radio name="radioGroup">
                            Option 2
                        </Radio>{' '}
                        <Radio name="radioGroup">
                            Option 3
                        </Radio>
                    </FormGroup>
                    </div>
        {/****************************************Next Question Button************************************************/}
                    <div className="next-question-button-container">
                        <Button onClick={this.changeQuestion} bsClass="xavor-style">Next</Button>
                    </div>
        {/*********************************End of Next Question Button************************************************/}
                </div>
                
            </Aux>

        );
    }
}

export default TestScreen;
```

The problem I am facing is that the time rendered on the screen is one step behind the updated state. Since I am using a callback function to update the state, the value shown on the console is accurate but the rendered value in my JSX is one step behind.
For example: if my console prints "state Time: 1" the value rendered will be 0:02.
How can I update rendered value of state? Any help or suggestions will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You are redirecting while rendering when time hits 0. That's why you don't get to see 0:00. Instead of redirecting directly. Check after the render in `componentDidUpdate`, if `time === 0`, and if so clear the interval, and update the `redirect` property on the state. When rerendering the view, the `redirect: true` state will trigger the actual redirect.

**Note:** React's [setState](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate) is asynchronous. When a state update is dependant on current state, it's better to use the updater method.

```
class TestScreen extends Component{

  state = {
      total_questions:60,
      current_question:1,
      time: 50,
      minutes: null,
      seconds: null,
      redirect: false,
  };

  changeQuestion = () =>
    this.setState((prevState) => ({
      current_question: prevState.current_question + 1
    }));

  componentDidMount() {
    // assign the timer to this.timer, so you can clear it in componentWillUnmount
    this.timer = setInterval(() =>
      this.setState(({ time }) => ({
        minutes: time / 60,
        seconds: ("0" + time % 60).slice(-2),
        time: time - 1
      }))
    , 1000)
  }

  componentDidUpdate() {
    const { time, redirect } = this.state;

    if(!reidrect && time === 0 && ) {
      clearInterval(this.timer);

      this.setState({
        redirect: true
      });
    }
  }

  render() {
    const { time, redirect, minutes, seconds } = this.state;

    // just the relevant JSX parts
    return (
      <div className="test-timer">
        {redirect ?  <Redirect to='/' /> : console.log("Some Error Occured")}
        <h3>{minutes}:{seconds}</h3>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried to do so but the result is the same. I don't know much about how react works but what if there is a way to maybe render the value of state in JSX AFTER the setState function is called? I got the Asynchronous behavior part of your answer, I just can't figure out a work around. Because according to the logic I have implemented, The page is to be redirected after time ends and as soon as the timer hits 0:02, it redirects which kind of looks too ugly right now.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I eventually found something I was missing. I was printing the value of the state variable "time" in my console whereas I was rendering the value of minutes and seconds. I still don't know why minutes and seconds were updated later but, the way I got it working was implementing the logic in the JSX instead of setting the state variables.

Comment: I appreciate the clarification on the redirect part. It is more organized I believe. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Keep your timer and question both in separate component, timerComponent should not render. Just render your questionComponent and pass the the time to your questionComponent as a props.